# Url encoding in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am binding a div with the image list which returned from server side method.

Like below:

```
  $("#GalleryPhotos").append("<div class='thumbnail'><a rel='group1' data-caption='caption'  class='fancybox'  href=" + data.d[i] + "><img  height='120' width='150' src=" + data.d[i] + "></img></a> </div> ");
```

I will get complete url

```
 < img src= "/UploadedFiles/Gallery/CricketAlbum/5335.jpg" />
```

It is showing correctly if there is no space in file name, But in case if there is a space in file name it is rendering as:

```
 < img  src="/UploadedFiles/Gallery/Birdst" album="" sample_05.jpg="" />
```

I tried javascript built in function encode like this **src="+ encodeURI(data.d[i])+"** But still my img getting rendered as in second case..Please help me somebody

Comment: Incidentally, `<img />` is a void element, it has no closing tag. And if you're appending to an existing URL, you want `encodeURIComponent()`, not `encodeURI()`.

Comment: No you should do decodeURI right?

Comment: i am thinking that mi8 not be problem,,if it is the actual problem all image names with space and with out space should't hv rendred..plz correct me if im wrong

Comment: Can you give us sample output of `console.log( data.d[i] )`.

Comment: encrodeURIComponent is wrking ..Thx for ur suggestions @David

Comment: The space should be a `%20` so it would be `src="/UploadedFiles/Gallery/Birdst%20album%20sample_05.jpg"`

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @DavidThomas, use `encodeURIComponent()`:

```
 ..  width='150' src='" + encodeURIComponent( data.d[i] ) + "'></a> ..
```

**Special Note**

The primary reason this was not working is because you were not putting the value of `src` in quotes. In effect you were writing:

```
<img  src=/UploadedFiles/Gallery/Birdst album sample_05.jpg />
```

Which would process into the weird attributes you were seeing. However, if you had quoted the value, the URL may as well have worked:

```
< img  src='/UploadedFiles/Gallery/Birdst album sample_05.jpg' />
```

The code should have been:

```
.... src='" + data.d[i] + "'>....
```

Or:

```
.... src=\"" + data.d[i] + "\">....
```

Now that you know that much, however, it is always safer to escape URLs as unescaped characters may produce undesired results in certain system:

```
.... src=\"" + encodeURIComponent( data.d[i] ) + "\" ....
```

Comment: simply encodeURIComponent is worked for me...but what ever u suggested are alsoo worthyy

Comment: Great! Please accept this answer `iff` it was helpful.